# How to download the Netbeans IDE onto an external hard drive

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to download and save the Netbeans IDE onto my external hard drive as I have minimal space on my laptop, but for some reason, it's not letting me download the installer onto my hard drive.

Is there a way that I can download the installer onto my external hard drive?

Comment: How in your opinion should we be able to find out what's going on on your computer?

Comment: @Connum I was just wondering in general if there's an option to save the installer to an external hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Please, read this if you want to run Netbeans from external drive: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqPortableWorkingEnvironments

For download NetBeans with the "Save as" and then choose your external drive, here you have some links, depending of the version you need: https://netbeans.org/downloads/zip.html

You can too download the .exe or .dmg ... or another extension, opening the download link, cancelling the download launched (download into the computer) and using the traditional right click-save as in the link: "Your download should start automatically. If not, download it here."

Any way, i think your best solution, if you will work too much with NetBeans, is to do space for it into your computer :)